# Swift Singleton class to store user settings

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an AppSettings class to store user setttings in an user dictionary. My AppSettings class:

```
class AppSettings : NSObject
{
    static var user: [String: Any]?

    static let sharedSingleton : AppSettings = {
        let instance = AppSettings()
        return instance
    }()

    var userID: String?
    var baseUrl: String?

    override private init() {

        super.init()
       let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

       AppSettings.user = userDefaults.object(forKey: "user") as! [String : Any]?
        print(AppSettings.user ?? "User Defaults has no values")

        self.saveSettings()
    }

    func saveSettings()
    {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if((AppSettings.user) != nil)
        {
            userDefaults.set(AppSettings.user, forKey: "user")
        }
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

I am storing values in user this way:

```
AppSettings.user?["User_ID"] = String(describing: dictionary["User_ID"])
AppSettings.sharedSingleton.saveSettings()

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "user")
                    print(defaults ?? "User is null")
```

It shows that User is null. What's wrong?

Comment: Does your AppSettings.user have content when you print it or you get "User Defaults has no values"  ?

Comment: I get  "User Defaults has no values". I've not been able to add values

Comment: You never set any data for the key "user". You try to get the object but you never set it so it will return nil. And when you try to save it you check for nil, which is always nil, so you never save it. So you need to at least initialize a "user" object somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your example is complete, the problem lies in this line

```
AppSettings.user?["User_ID"] = String(describing: dictionary["User_ID"])
```

The `user` variable is an optional, so unless you created an empty dictionary first this is what happens - if `user` is not nil, assign a value under `"User_ID"` key.

All you need to do is write `AppSetting.user = [String:Any]()` before trying to add values to it. Now, it may seem that you do it in `init()`, but it's not called unless you call `sharedInstace`.

On a side note - if you are making this a singleton, why do you expose the `user` variable as a `static`?

Comment: I don't know, why I made it static. I am now calling `AppSetting.user = [String:Any]()` in init() So how should I add values in it?

Comment: As long as the `init` gets run before you access `AppSetting.user`, everything will work.

Comment: Best way would be to make `user` not `static` and access it as `AppSetting.sharedSingletion.user`